# Why did Paypal API suddenly stop working when authenticating using this endpoint? (svcs.paypal.com/Permissions/RequestPermissions)

Tags: php, soap, paypal

I'm making a request to this endpoint.

`https://svcs.paypal.com/Permissions/RequestPermissions?requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US&scope(0)=ACCESS_BASIC_PERSONAL_DATA&scope(1)=ACCOUNT_BALANCE&scope(2)=TRANSACTION_SEARCH&callback=callbackurl.com/{state_id}`

I am also using these headers

`array('X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: ______', 'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: ______', 'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: ______', 'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV', 'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON', 'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: ______')`

Sometime in beginning of January this was noticed there was an issue. The API is returning a response of

```
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [errorId] => 550001
            [domain] => PLATFORM
            [subdomain] => Application
            [severity] => Error
            [category] => Application
            [message] => User is not allowed to perform this action
        )

)
```

I'm currently using the NVP/SOAP API credentials provided by Paypal. I can't find anything in documentation or changelog that leads me to believe something was updated or deprecated in the API.

Comment: `User is not allowed to perform this action` looks like a permissions issue. You may need to contact Paypal.